# Play Click/Tick sound on every count down in seconds(iPhone)?

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have implemented a down counter which plays Click sound on every second till it's timer get invalidated. At the same time,I m displaying the counter value.

```
  -(IBAction)start{
    myTicker =[NSTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showactivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }

        -(void)showactivity;{

        int CurrentTime =[time.textintValue];

        NSString *soundFilePath=[[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:@"Click03" ofType:@"wav"];
        NSURL *soundFileURL =[NSURLfileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
        AVAudioPlayer *player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
        player.numberOfLoops =1;
        [player play];

        int newTime = CurrentTime-1;
        time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newTime];
        if(newTime ==0){
                [myTicker invalidate];
        time.text = @"0";

            }

        }
```

Counter works perfectly but with a small initial delay; But it doesn't play the sound,Can anyone help me to implement this concept efficiently, with a minimum delays etc...

Comment: if you are using `ARC`, the local `AVAudioPlayer` object will be  automatically deallocated after the block finished. because there is no other strong pointer which keeps it alive, so there is no chance so hear/play your sound... the solution is instead of the local `AVAudioPlayer` instance use a global one in your class.

Comment: @holex - Yeah, It works well with the global one, Then i need to load the sound file in ViewDidLoad and use it inside -(void)showactivity{}, Is it a better programming technique? I think programming is not all about doing the work as intended, But to be in the smartest way!! :)

Comment: if you work with same sound effect at whole time, it would be easier to load it only once, i.e. in `-viewDidLoad` method. you can save some resources with this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a sound that is one second long consisting of a click followed by 1 second (minus the duration of the click) of samples of silence. Set the `player.numberOfLoops` to however many seconds you have to count down, and just play it once.

Answer (score 0):

To play the sound using AVAudioPlayer

1) Add

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

to your header file

remember to synthesize it in your .m file

2) initialize the player and play the sound with following code:

```
        NSString *soundFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yourSoundFile" ofType:@"caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSError *err = nil;

    self.player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&err];

    self.player.numberOfLoops = 0;

    if ([self.player play]) {
        NSLog(@"playing sound");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"COULD NOT play sound");
    };
```

note that setting self.player.numberOfLoops to 0 will play the sound one time. Setting it to 1, will loop it once, resulting in sound playing twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, solving the ARC deallocing problem, is to add all the players to an array. Then set yourself as the player's delegate, listening to when the audio finished playing and then remove it from the array. That way, the player won't be deallocated before it has finished playing. Something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *playersArray

-(void)showactivity
{
    int CurrentTime =[time.textintValue];

    NSString *soundFilePath=[[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:@"Click03" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL =[NSURLfileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer *player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops =1;
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
    [self.playersArray addObject:player];

    int newTime = CurrentTime-1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newTime];
    if (newTime == 0) {
        [myTicker invalidate];
        time.text = @"0";
    }
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [playersArray removeObject:player];
}
```

Remember to initialise your array.